# Memory overflow in Python

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have 67000 files, I need to read them and extract similarities between the words, but when I run the code my laptop becomes much slower, I can't open any other application, and then a memory overflow error shows up (even when I run on around 10 000 of the files). Is there a way to clear the memory after every for loop maybe, or will running the code on all files be impossible to do? Below is the code:

```
def isAscii(s):
    for c in s:
        if c not in string.printable:
            return False
    return True


windowSize = 2

relationTable = {}
probabilities = {}
wordCount = {}

totalWordCount = 0

def sim(w1, w2):
    numerator = 0
    denominator = 0
    if (w1 in relationTable) and (w2 in relationTable):
        rtw1 = {}
        rtw2 = {}
        rtw1 = relationTable[w1]
        rtw2 = relationTable[w2]
        for word in rtw1:
            rtw1_PMI = rtw1[word]['pairPMI']           
            denominator += rtw1_PMI
            if(word in rtw2):
                rtw2_PMI = rtw2[word]['pairPMI']
                numerator += (rtw1_PMI + rtw2_PMI)

        for word in rtw2:
            rtw2_PMI = rtw2[word]['pairPMI'] 
            denominator += rtw2_PMI

        if(denominator != 0):
            return float(numerator)/denominator
        else:
            return 0

    else:
        return -1



AllNotes = {}
AllNotes = os.listdir("C:/Users/nerry-san/Desktop/EECE 502/MedicalNotes")

fileStopPunctuations = open('C:/Users/nerry-san/Desktop/EECE 502/stopPunctuations.txt')
stopPunctuations = nltk.word_tokenize(fileStopPunctuations.read())


for x in range (0, 10):
    fileToRead = open('C:/Users/nerry-san/Desktop/EECE 502/MedicalNotes/%s'%(AllNotes[x]))


    case1 = fileToRead.read()
    text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(case1.lower())


    final_text = []
    for index in range(len(text)):
        word = text[index]
        if (word not in stopPunctuations):
            final_text.append(word)            

    for index in range (len(final_text)):
        w1 = final_text[index]
        if(isAscii(w1)):
            for index2 in range(-windowSize, windowSize+1):
                if (index2 != 0):
                    if ( index + index2 ) in range (0, len(final_text)):
                        w2 = final_text[index + index2]

                        if(isAscii(w2)):
                            totalWordCount += 1
                            if (w1 not in wordCount):
                                wordCount[w1] = {}
                                wordCount[w1]['wCount'] = 0

                            try:
                                wordCount[w1][w2]['count'] += 1
                                wordCount[w1]['wCount'] += 1
                            except KeyError:
                                wordCount[w1][w2] = {'count':1}
                                wordCount[w1]['wCount'] += 1 


for word in wordCount:
    probabilities[word]={}
    probabilities[word]['wordProb'] = float (wordCount[word]['wCount'])/ totalWordCount



for word in wordCount:
    relationTable[word] = {}
    for word2 in wordCount[word]:    
        if ( word2 != 'wCount'):          
            pairProb = float(wordCount[word][word2]['count'])/(wordCount[word]['wCount'])

            relationTable[word][word2] = {}
            relationTable[word][word2]['pairPMI'] = math.log(float(pairProb)/(probabilities[word]['wordProb'] * probabilities[word2]['wordProb']),2)

l = []
for word in relationTable:
    l.append(word)

for index in range (0, len(l)):
    word = l[index] 
    simValues = []
    for index2 in range (0, len(l)):
        word2 = l[index2]
        if(word!= word2):
            simVal = sim(word,word2)
            if(simVal > 0):
                simValues.append([word2, simVal])

    simValues.sort(key= operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

Comment: It's probably not a memory leak. Your script is just using up all of your RAM.

Comment: You could try out using a database instead?

Comment: You may want to consider (a) closing your files when you're done with them, and (b) refactoring intermediate computation into functions (which have their own scope, so the GC can clean up intermediate values that are only used within those functions). Not that I think either of these is more than 5% likely to solve your problem, but they're worth doing anyway.

Comment: Also… where are you opening these 10000 files? I see that you get a list of filenames with `listdir`, but you never iterate over it. And then you've got a loop that opens one file each time through the loop, but you only do it 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open a file, use the "with" statement.  This will ensure the file is closed when the loop finishes (or rather when the with block is exited.